Extracting Sublists Based on Pairwise Inequality Conditions
To find two sublists from the list generated by Subsets[{a, b, c}, {2}] such that the elements in the same positions are not the same.
The generated two-element subsets are {{a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}}. Our goal is to find two of these subsets where the first element and the second element are different.
Given  only have three elements, there is actually only one pair of subsets that satisfies the condition, which is {{a, b}, {b, c}}.
I tried it,but not achieve this goal
Select[Subsets[Subsets[{a, b, c}, {2}], {2}], 
 MatchQ[#, {{x_, y_}, {u_, v_}} /; x != u && y != v] &]



Select[Subsets[Subsets[{a, b, c}, {2}], {2}], 
  UnsameQ @@ #[[All, 1]] && UnsameQ @@ #[[All, 2]] &] // 
 Flatten[#, 1] &


Also: First@Gather[Union@Flatten[Subsets[Subsets[{a, b, c}, {2}], {2}], 1], #1[[1]] =!= #2[[1]] && #1[[2]] =!= #2[[2]] &]
